# R Instance of S4 object with S3 attribute

Tags: r, oop, zoo, r-s4

I am currently creating a new S4 class which uses a S3 zoo object. I can create a class

```
setOldClass("zoo")
setClass("rollingSD", slot = c(rollPeriod = "numeric", tsOutput = "zoo"))
```

This code works fine. Now if I want to create an object as

```
 riskSD <- new("rollingSD")
```

This also works fine. However, the following generates an error

```
riskSD <- new("rollingSD", rollPeriod = 12)
Error in validObject(.Object) :
invalid class “rollingSD” object: invalid object for slot "tsOutput" in class  
"rollingSD": got class "S4", should be or extend class "zoo"
```

This not clear for me why a default object of the zoo class is not inititated. I also do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because R's class mechanism doesn't know how to make a new `zoo` object. You can fix this by specifying a "prototype":

```
setClass(
  "rollingSD",
  slot = c(rollPeriod = "numeric", tsOutput = "zoo"),
  prototype=prototype(
    tsOutput=some_zoo_object
  )
)
```

where `some_zoo_object` is of class `zoo`. The default prototype for a `numeric` slot is `numeric()`, but because you defined the (S4) class `zoo` yourself, the default is `new("zoo")` and this isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense indeed. I would suggest to take `some_zoo_object = zoo()` . That is the closest we can get to for a default object with zoo class.